# Uploading public files to Amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, lamp

I have set up an Amazon EC2 instance with `Apache`, `PHP`, and `MySQL` (`LAMP`) using [this](http://www.robotmedia.net/2011/04/how-to-create-an-amazon-ec2-instance-with-apache-php-and-mysql-lamp/comment-page-1/#comments) tutorial.

All of that is working correctly, including `phpMyAdmin`, and you should be able to see the success page at:

```
http://54.235.216.209/
```

Now, I'm lost on how to upload public files, and change the default index page. I've successfully connected with `Filezilla` and created a `/var/www/html` directory in which I placed all my files. These also show up when I `SSH` in. However, when I navigate to

```
http://54.235.216.209/var/www/html
```

or any variation, it says these directories do not exist. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory `/var/www/` is usually the root of the Web server, so you should not include it in the URL. Try accessing the files under:

```
http://54.235.216.209/html/
```

If the above does not work, try with (in case the Web root is mapped to `/var/www/html`):

```
http://54.235.216.209/
```

Comment: It looks like the folder I'm accessing via SFTP is home/ubuntu/. I just moved the html folder into /ubuntu/, but still no luck. I also cannot access the home folder. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of DocumentRoot in the Apache config ? The site config is usually under `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` in Ubuntu.

Comment: According to sites-enabled, the DocumentRoot is /var/www. But if I navigate to (my address)/var, it says that doesn't exist.

Comment: Again, DO NOT include neither `var` or `www` in your URL. Files you place under `/var/www/` should be accessible directly from `http://yourAdress/`. If they are not, something is probably wrong with your installation. Did you install Apache using `apt-get` ?

Comment: They are not accessible there. I do believe I installed Apache using apt-get, as stated in my original question I used that tutorial. Would it be a better idea to restart the process, and possibly not follow that tutorial?

Comment: That tutorial uses a Community AMI. Some Community AMIs are very good, but sometimes they use non-standard (and undocumented) configuration and can be harder to troubleshoot for that reason. I would recommend using a stock AMI like the default Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

File paths served by `Apache` don't start at the root directory, they start at whatever the `Apache` `DocumentRoot` is set to. For example, if `DocumentRoot` was set to `/var/www` then the path to your files would start with `/html`.

```
http://198.51.100.209/html/
```

`/var/www/html` is the physical directory on the server and `Apache` is pointing to this directory as `Apache's` root. This mapping makes `/var/www/html` effectively `/` from a `URL` perspective. So `http://54.235.216.209/` will give you all the files under `/var/www/html`.

Comment: You are correct, the DocumentRoot is /var/www. However, if I navigate to (my IP)/html/, it says that directory does not exist.

Comment: Are the permissions on html/ such that the user Apache is running as can access this directory? Also I'd be checking Apache's error_log (/var/log/httpd/error_log) for guidance.